# How do I get this inequality

Tags: inequality

$2d/(1+d^2)\leq 2/d$

How did he get from the thing on the left to the thing on the right? <= is less than or equal to.

And also, where do I learn how to typ mathematics symbol on the computer like they are written on paper?

Thnx

Comment: Hint: $d^2 < 1+d^2$. And you can enclose math within "dollar" signs. Click edit to see.

Comment: This site uses MathJax there is a tutorial [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/q/5020/86986)

Answer (score 1):

If e.g. $d=-1$ then it is not true. It is true under the extra condition that $d>0$. In that case divide numerator and denominator both by $d$ resulting in:
$$\frac{2d}{1+d^{2}}=\frac{2}{\frac{1}{d}+d}$$

Note that $\frac{1}{d}+d>d$ implying that $\frac{2}{\frac{1}{d}+d}<\frac{2}{d}$

Also note that you have $$\frac{2d}{1+d^{2}}<\frac{2}{d}$$

wich is a bit more than you asked for (equality is excluded).

Comment: thanks for the explanation, but when is the equality equal, I don't think it can be, because then (1/d)+d=d and that becomes 1=0 which is nonsense.

The problem was also a limit when d->infinity, that's why the book used this rewriting/inequality. The problem was more of the nature, how do you see it, or come up with it yourself!

Comment: You are right. As I said 'equality is excluded'. It is a *strict* inequality. This because $1/d$ cannot equalize $0$.

Comment: If $d$ goes to $+\infty$ then it is immediately clear that $2/d$ goes to zero. Then the inequality can be used to come to the conclusion that also $\frac{2d}{1+d^2}$ goes to zero. here $2/d$ is just a more 'simple' expression than $\frac{2d}{1+d^2}$ and they are taking advantage of that.

Comment: To avoid confusion: As I said the inequality is strict, but that does
not mean that $\frac{2d}{1+d^{2}}\leq\frac{2}{d}$ is not true. It
is true and can be used in order to prove that $\lim_{d\rightarrow+\infty}\frac{2d}{1+d^{2}}=0$.
That's probably the reason that the book makes no point of *strict*
or *not strict*.

Answer (score 1):

Valuable points:

If $$\frac{a}{b}<\frac{c}{d}$$ then

- If $b>0, d<0$ then $ad>bc$.
- If $b>0,d>0$ then $ad<bc$

Here note that $1+d^2>0$ **always**.